# Adding files to Document & Media Library programmatically on start of liferay server

Tags: svn, storage, liferay, document

I would like to commit 2 files in SVN structure so any start on our Liferay server includes by default two registered files in Document and Media Library.

Is there any way to programmatically add/edit a file in Documents and Media Library?

Where is the best place to put this kind of `init()` (initialization) code for the server?

Comment: The requirement is not exactly clear: Do you want that on start of Liferay Server you want to automatically upload 2 files from a specific location (SVN) to Liferay's Documents & Media Portlet?

Comment: Yes, the server is always containing both files and its custom fileEntryType, (unless its overriden in runtime and persisted during same version). But everytime you check the server from scratch from svn it includes both files registered by default.

Comment: So these 2 files are already present in `D&M portlet` and you want to update these files from SVN on server restart and you don't want a fresh upload (i.e. create) these files in `D & M Portlet`? Am I right?

Comment: I want to avoid manually adding and defining docs through LR Control Panel interface every time I download server project from SVN. I want this functionality to come bundled by default or emulated programmatically on some code for the first server run. Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Make a `hook` and define the following in `portal.properties`:

`application.startup.events=com.my.TwoDocumentsOnStartOfLiferayCreator`

(see [Extending & Overriding *portal.properties*](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/extending-and-overriding-%3Cem%3Eportal-properties%3C-e-3) section in Liferay [Developer Guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/liferay-portal-6-1-development-guide)).

Now, the `TwoDocumentsOnStartOfLiferayCreator` class will be execute on every start of Liferay portal server. In `TwoDocumentsOnStartOfLiferayCreator` you can check for existing documents, update or create new if necessary.

Creating documents programmatically is not so simple but liferay has provided API for creating/updating/deleting documents. You can start by checking liferay's source code for [`EditFileEntryAction#updateFileEntry()`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/action/EditFileEntryAction.java#L783) method.